# magento: extra email recipients in order confirmation email

Tags: email, magento, confirmation

i have a peculiar problem, when customers receive an order confirmation email strangely this is also sent to some other older customers. I have searched file after file and do not know where this code is inserted, a previous developer inserted this and now very important i remove it. Which file is responsible to send out the new order confirmation email?

Comment: Maybe you should check your database as well.

Comment: Check your core_email_queue and core_email_recipients table. If still unable to find it then try to find "sendNewOrderEmail()" inside app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php . If still unable to track it properly then you can also try "lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php or smtp.php (these files are used to send all emails in magento)"

Comment: i checked the table and it seems corrupted with same message_id for many customers, would it be wise to delete the table or go through the table and change the message_id

Answer (score 0):

Check Your code on below location

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

**Or**(if file is override)

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

and find function around line no.`1274`

```
public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
```

and check  `$emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);` function

Comment: i checked the table and it seems corrupted with same message_id for many customers, would it be wise to delete the table or go through the table and change the message_id

Comment: I don't know what you talking about.If you are new to magento, then never play with tables,ask developer to change it or try to change from admin panel if it's few